# Solving inequality with conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have been trying to solve the inequality given by:
\begin{equation}
\Bigg|\Bigg(\frac{Bx}{R}\Bigg)^2\times\frac{(k+1)^{k-1}}{(k-2)}\Bigg|<\frac{(k-1)^{k-1}}{k^k}\end{equation}

I need to solve this equation to find out the condition on $k$, that is, i need the interval in which $k$ lies, given that $k$ is a positive integer.

I realize that the above inequality can be expanded, and by doing so, I have got:
\begin{equation}
-\Bigg(\frac{R}{Bx}\Bigg)^2<\frac{(k+1)^{k-1}k^k}{(k-2)(k-1)^{k-1}}<\Bigg(\frac{R}{Bx}\Bigg)^2
\end{equation}

However, I am not able to go any further. $B$ and $x$ are positive integers with $B>>x$, and $R$ is a positive real number with $R<<Bx$

From the denominator of the term containing k, it is evident that $k\neq0, k\neq1$ and $k\neq2$. However, I can't say anything further about the interval in which $k$ resides.

Please help me find the interval in whivh $k$ resides.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer after a bit of brainstorming.

Since the value of $k\nless3$, the term with $k$ shall always be a positive value $>1$

Now, $\frac{R}{Bx}$ will always be a positive fraction. hence, there is no solution for k satisfying this inequality.